# fetch all links under/in a specific class-selenium webdriver (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to fetch all the links under a specific class?

The thing is, iI am writing a test that requires me to click on a random `item/product` but if a create a list of all the links through `By.tagName("a")`, It'll fetch ALL the links on the page. To be more exact, consider [this website](http://www.beechtree.pk/), Now I want to randomly choose from `pret`,`summer` `sale`,`accessories`, `bt lawn'16`, `sale`, `lookbook` or after clicking on `summer sale`, I want to randomly click on one of the products under it. any idea how to do it?

here is a snippet of my program :

[image: https]

Comment: Do want randomly click on each run?? what is the problem with your code??

Comment: yes i want random clicks on each turn but i want those random clicks on a specific area of page/on some specific links on page. but the code i wrote above will fetch all the links on the current page

Comment: Ok see the answer, it will random click on these `pret`,`summer` `sale`, `accessories`, `bt lawn'16`, `sale`, `lookbook` links...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are using incorrect `xpath` to locating `pret`,`summer` `sale`,`accessories`, `bt lawn'16`, `sale`, `lookbook`, links try as below :-

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.level0"));
Random random = new Random();
WebElement randomLink = allLinks.get(random.nextInt(allLinks.size()));
randomLink.click();
```

Comment: ok so from what i get, it'll create a list of webelements that contains all the links at level 10 i.e summer sale etc and then the web element randomlink selects randomly from this list and clicks on it?

Comment: @SaraIftikhar, Yes, but it's class is `level0` not `level10`...:)

Comment: thanks alot.But is there a way to do it through xpath instead of css selector? this method works perfectly fine just want to know if more ways exist....

Comment: @SaraIftikhar I would suggest you, always give priority to cssSlector because it's much faster than xpath, and if you want to know xpath for this is just simple as `.//a[contains(@class, 'level0')]`...:)

Comment: hey another thing, is there an easy way to find out which class is the link associated with? i usually use xpath so if i have to use css selector i go through the code manually to see wchich class it belongs to

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the classes from the site you mentioned, please use below xpath:

```
List<WebElement> allMenus = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'level0')]"));
```

Then loop through the `WebElements` to get to the desired menu item. Also, it is observed that the sub-menu items are getting displayed after the mouse is hovered on a particular item. To perform the mouse hover operation we have to use `Actions` class. Please find the below code for your reference.

```
Actions mouseHovers = new Actions(driver);
// Looping through the menu items stored in the above list variable
for(WebElement eachMenu : allMenus) {
    mouseHovers.moveToElement(eachMenu).perform();
    // Select the desired sub-menu by using the above line of code by replacing the "eachMenu" element with the respective sub-menu element.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't want to select all the classes, i want to chose all the links in that class. for example i want all the links of products under the class product-list.