# How to click the links randomly in webpage using java,selenium

Tags: java, selenium

http://www.toysrus.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=2535588&sr=1&origkw=watches

In the above web page lots of products are available, we need to click the product links randomly using java selenium. please help me out!

Comment: What have you tried? you could save elements in a list and use a random element from the list to click it.

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829086/fetch-all-links-under-in-a-specific-class-selenium-webdriver-java/38830443#38830443

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('a.prodtitle'));
links.get(new Random().nextInt(links.size())).click();
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

The answer already posted will only click one link at random. If you eventually want to click every link randomly, then you will need to keep some sort of record of what links you have visited already. You will also need to go back after visiting a page.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('a.prodtitle'));
List<WebElement> visited = new List<WebElement>();
WebElement random = links.get(new Random().nextInt(links.size()));
if( !visited.contains(random))
{ 
    random.click();
    visited.add(random);
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```